# How to exclude a file from Apache limit directive

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

We currently have a .htaccess file which looks like

```
<Limit GET POST>
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from localhost
allow from ...
</Limit>
```

This applies currently to the whole directory. I would like to exclude one file in the directory from these rules so that it could accessed from the whole Internet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm not sure what the purpose of the `Limit` directive is here. It has the effect of allowing all clients to use these HTTP methods: PUT, DELETE, CONNECT, OPTIONS, PATCH, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, LOCK, and UNLOCK. Wouldn't you rather wish to restrict all methods, not just GET and POST?)

You could use the `Files` (or `FilesMatch`) directives like so:

```
<Files "foo.html">
    allow from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mod_rewrite and [F] flag:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}  !127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}  !192.168.0.1
RewriteRule !^foo$ - [F]
```